# Is the unit ball complete in the 2-norm of tracial von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $V$ be a tracial von Neumann algebra i.e a von Neumann algebra with a tracial faithful normal state $\tau$. It is known that the trace induces a norm on the von Neumann algebra defined by $||a||_2^{2} = \tau(a^*a)$. And this norm metricizes the strong operator topology on bounded sets (bounded with respect to the operator norm). My question is the unit ball (with the respect to the operator norm) of the von Neumann algebra complete with respect to this norm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. This is Proposition 2.6.4 in [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIunV15.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epopa/Books/IIunV15.pdf)

Comment: There is also a kind of converse to this statement: If $\tau$ is a faithful trace on a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ and the unit ball of $A$ is complete in the $2$-norm, then $A$ is a von Neumann algebra. This can be used for example to show that the tracial ultraproduct of von Neumann algebras is again a (tracial) von Neumann algebra.